# How to monitor Oracle temp space for specific object like Clob\Blob

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I am new to Oracle and i wanted to know if there is a way to monitor Clob\Blob objects allocation in Oracle Temp Space.

With JDBC 4.0, we have clob.free() and blob.free() methods and i want a way to verify the benefits using these methods in my application.

Does anyone know how can i do that and/or possibly point me in the right direction?

Comment: I like this question. What is exactly the API/procedure you use to create a clob?

Comment: Run your app, allocate some `CLOB/BLOB` objects. Check the memory used by your application. Call `.free()` on the allocated objects. Force a `gc`, check the memory consumption again. Maybe that's what you are looking for. Otherwise be more precise in your question.

Comment: I think the OP talks about the storage used in Oracle, not about memory.

Comment: @SubOptimal Hi, Thanks for your input but i am looking for Database memory consumption monitoring.

Comment: Have you check my answer? Does any of the statements answer your question? If not, please be more precise in what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

You can start with this statement it will show you the free MB in the LOB tablespace used by the CLOB/BLOB columns of a table

```
select fs.tablespace_name,
       sum (fs.bytes) / 1024 / 1024 mb_free
from dba_free_space fs
join dba_lobs lo on lo.tablespace_name = fs.tablespace_name
where lo.table_name = 'YOUR_TABLE_NAME'
and lo.owner = 'SCHEMA_NAME'
group by fs.tablespace_name
```

If you want to monitor the free temporary tablespace which contains object only for the duration of a session you can start with this statement.

```
select tf.free_space / 1024 / 1024 mb_free
from dba_temp_free_space tf;
```

Comment: I don't see what is about TEMP here.

Comment: @FlorinGhita Thanks for the hint. I added the statement to my answer.